# Tikz name path problems: No shape names is known

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I seem to struggle already with the simplest use case of `name path` in Tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[name path=A,thick] (0,0) circle[radius=0.1];%
        \draw[name path=B,thick] (1,1) circle[radius=0.1];%
        \draw (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}%
```

which gives me:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named A is known. \draw (A)
Package pgf Error: No shape named B is known. \draw (A) -- (B)
Package pgf Error: No shape named B is known. \draw (A) -- (B)
Package pgf Error: No shape named A is known. \draw (A) -- (B)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `A` and `B` are paths in your example, not nodes.

Comment: @marmot, so I have to use `\node[draw=black,circle,minimum size=10pt] (A) at (0,0) {}%` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your code, you may not even need to use intersections. Let's look at the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box=what you want]
      \path (0,0) node[circle,draw,thick,inner sep=1mm-\pgflinewidth] (A){} 
      (1,1) node[circle,draw,thick,inner sep=1mm-\pgflinewidth] (B){};%
      \draw (A) -- (B);
      \end{scope}
      \node[above=of what you want]{Is this what you want?};
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box=intersections,xshift=7cm,yshift=-1.9cm]
        \draw[name path=A,thick] (0,0) circle[radius=2];%
        \draw[name path=B,thick] (1,1) circle[radius=2];%
        \draw[name intersections={of=A and B}] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2);
      \end{scope}
      \node[above=of intersections]{What you can do with intersections};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}%
```

[image]

On the left, a line between two objects (nodes) named `A` and `B` is drawn. On the right, intersections are used. Of course, intersections can only be used if there are paths that intersect. Here the intersections of two paths (not nodes!) `A` and `B` are computed and connected by a line.

Note:

1. The nodes and paths `A` and `B` are two different objects. Yes, you can use the same symbol for both and Ti*k*Z won't get confused.
2. You could name the path of a node also by a letter.

I try to illustrate the second point with an example in which the path of a node has also a name, and is used in intersections.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[name path=A,circle,draw,text width=2cm] (B) at (0,0){I'm a node with
     name B whose boundary path has the name A};
     \draw[name path=C] (-4,4) -- (4,-4);
     \draw[name intersections={of=A and C},latex-latex] (intersection-1) 
     to[bend right] (intersection-2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}%
```

[image]